# how to implement arabic rating bar in android

Tags: android, rating, ratingbar

please help me to do this, I need to implement ARABIC rating(Reverse) bar into my application.When I change my application locale into Arabic the rating bar should be reversed. I stuck with this for long.

Answer (score 0):

You mean `RatingBar` with RTL

In Android 4.2, RTL is supported, AFAIK. In your question. We can use this attribute`android:mirrorForRtl` to `RatingBar`

Here's an example

```
<RatingBar
        android:mirrorForRtl="true"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

You must also put `android:supportsRtl="true"` in `<application >` which is in Manifest file OR this will have no effect. By default, `android:supportsRtl` is set to `false`.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rtl" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:supportsRtl="true" >
```

Comment: And please, if this solution solved your problem. Please press check button. This will be helpful to others :)